# ARPACK is not compiling in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, arpack

I have change the ARmake.inc file accordingly. The platform is changed into LINUX. Following is the the problem:

```
root@sid-OptiPlex-7010:/home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK# make lib
/bin/sh: 4: cd: can't cd to home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/BLAS
Making lib in home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/BLAS
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK'
Unknown target single, try:  make help
Unknown target double, try:  make help
Unknown target complex, try:  make help
Unknown target complex16, try:  make help
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK'
/bin/sh: 4: cd: can't cd to home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/LAPACK
Making lib in home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/LAPACK
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sid/Downloads'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `single'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sid/Downloads'
/bin/sh: 4: cd: can't cd to home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/UTIL
Making lib in home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/UTIL
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sid'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `single'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sid'
/bin/sh: 4: cd: can't cd to home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/SRC
Making lib in home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/SRC
make[1]: Entering directory `/home'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `single'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home'
ranlib home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/libarpack_LINUX.a
ranlib: 'home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK/libarpack_LINUX.a': No such file
make: *** [arpacklib] Error 1
root@sid-OptiPlex-7010:/home/sid/Downloads/ARPACK#
```

Answer (score 1):

First create the source directly under `${HOME}` directory.Right now i guess its under `${HOME}/Downloads`. `${HOME}` for you is `/home/sid/`

Then do `cd ARPACK`

Make sure you have gfortran and make.
You can check it by typing :
`gfortran --version` or `make --version`.

Also open ARmake.inc and change home variable to

> > home = ${HOME}/ARPACK

Now type the following command in the terminal:

> make FC=gfortran FFLAGS= MAKE=/usr/bin/make ARPACKLIB=$HOME/ARPACK/libarpack.a lib

Make sure that `ARPACK` is directly under `/home/sid` and not in Downloads.